# Form submission in ExtJs 6

Tags: forms, extjs, extjs4, upgrade, extjs6

I have a form, that I submit with success and failure callbacks:

The view:

```
Ext.define('App.view.CommentForm', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.ship-commentForm',
    url: 'addcomment.php',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'textarea',
        fieldLabel: 'Comment',
        name: 'text',
        allowBlank: false,
        maxLength: 1000
    },{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        fieldLabel: 'User name',
        name: 'username',
        readOnly: true
    }],
    fbar: [{
        text: 'Save',
        formBind: true,
        itemId: 'submit'
    }]
})
```

And the controller:

```
Ext.define('App.controller.MyController', {
    init: function(){
        this.control({
            'ship-commentForm button#submit': {click: this.onFormSubmit},
...
    onFormSubmit: function(btn){ 
        var form = btn.up('form').getForm(),
        me = this,
        values = form.getValues();
        form.submit({
            success: function(form, action){
                console.log('success')
            },
            failure: function(form, action){
                console.log('failure')
            }
        })
        setTimeout(function(){btn.up('window').close()}, 100)
    },
```

While this worked great in ExtJs4, in ExtJs6, the form submits as it should, but the success and failure callbacks are no longer called. This should still work according to [the documentation of `submit()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.form.Basic.html#method-submit).

N.B. The server responds contains a valid JSON string:

```
{"success":true,"msg":"Comment saved"}
```

Edit: I just added the code in the controller that I suspect being the issue:
`setTimeout(btn.up('window').close(), 100)`

Comment: I have done a sample fiddle to test your issue  and it is working fine at my fiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1qjr

Comment: @SuryaPrakashTumma Thanks. I also managed to get it working in a fiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1qjq just a few moments ago. I'm not yet sure where the problem is.

Comment: Wouldn't be a better idea to call the `.close()` method inside de success callback of the `form.submit` ? Or this is some kind of requirement ?

Comment: @qmat You're right. That's the answer I finally found. Post it as answer, and I will accept yours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of closing your window with a `setTimeout`, make it in your success callback of the `form.submit()`. It should solve your problem.

```
form.submit({
    success: function(form, action){
        btn.up('window').close()
    },
    failure: function(form, action){
        console.log('failure')
    }
})
```